# where can i download android actual images such as the info symbol?

Tags: android, user-interface

I googled and found the docs on icon requirements and even a template file but I have not yet found how to obtain the actual images.  Hope someone can help.

Comment: I can't get your question about "actual images"...
You can find icons [here](http://www.iconfinder.com/) that can be used in your project easily..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all standard images are located in the sdk folder.

> android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-??\data\res\

check out the drawable* folders

Answer (score 0):

You will find the entire Android Source code (including the image resources) at http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/. Search for the image name.

HTH,

Akshay

Answer (score 0):

You can find some icons here http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/ (as of android 2.2).  To make icons, you can here http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html which will help you out :)